# "I do X if Y, and Z otherwise" vs. "I do X if Y, or Z otherwise"

Tags: difference, conjunctions, logic

Which one(s) amongst the following sentences are correct, and which one sounds the best?

- "I do X if Y, **and** Z otherwise"
- "I do X if Y, **or** Z otherwise"

Comment: How formal is this statement supposed to be?  Is this statement meant to be part of a contract, law, or regulation?  Or part of a computer program?  Or part of an essay?  Or just an off-hand comment to a friend?

Comment: @Jasper research article

Answer (score 1):

"Otherwise" is a conjunctive adverb, so an additional coordinating conjunction ("and", "or") is not needed. Replace the coordinating conjunction with a semicolon.

> If X, I do Y; otherwise, I do Z.

You can also use two separate sentences.

> If X, I do Y. Otherwise, I do Z.

Comment: Why a semicolon and not a comma?

Comment: A comma can be used with coordinating conjunctions (e.g. "and", "but", "or"), but not with conjunctive adverbs. As a rule, an adverb cannot join sentences.

Comment: Is that so?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_adverb (see "Placement") doesn't even mention a semicolon...

Comment: You don't have to use a semi colon, but you cannot use only a comma. Another valid option is two separate sentences. A semicolon is a good choice for two closely related sentences though.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly and literally as written, I suggest the second sentence sounds the best.

> **I do X if Y, or Z otherwise.**

My reasoning is more based in logic than grammar. The choices are an "either/or" proposition (i.e., mutually exclusive) and not a "both/and" proposition.

*Source: Native speaker*

Comment: One infallible source I'd say. :P